# Optimize sql query - wordpress - sql_big_selects

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I got a big sql query and need to simplify it somehow, any help appreciated.

I get this error: *WordPress database error: [The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay]*

I set $wpdb->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1') and site loads forever every time.

Don't want to use "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1", or wordpress meta_query, just to simplify the this query.

I opened a new question because i don't have proper skill in sql.

Query i'm using now:

```
        $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
            FROM
               $wpdb->posts,
               $wpdb->postmeta AS app_date,        
               $wpdb->postmeta AS provider,
               $wpdb->postmeta AS time1,
               $wpdb->postmeta AS time2,
               $wpdb->postmeta AS client

            WHERE
               $wpdb->posts.ID = app_date.post_id          
            AND
               $wpdb->posts.ID = provider.post_id
            AND
               $wpdb->posts.ID = time1.post_id
            AND
               $wpdb->posts.ID = time2.post_id
            AND
               $wpdb->posts.ID = client.post_id

            AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'ga_appointments'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status IN ('completed', 'publish', 'payment', 'pending')                 

            AND app_date.meta_key   = 'ga_appointment_date'
            AND app_date.meta_value = 2018-03-27

            AND provider.meta_key   = 'ga_appointment_provider'
            AND provider.meta_value = 55

            AND time1.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_time_end'
            AND time1.meta_value > 13:05

            AND time2.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_time'
            AND time2.meta_value < 14:05

            OR  client.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_client'
            AND client.meta_value REGEXP '\"email\";s:[1-9]+:\"jdoe@mail.com\"'

            OR  client.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_new_client'
            AND client.meta_value REGEXP '\"phone\";s:[1-9]+:\"999-656-5656\"'
        ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to put proper parenthesis near your 'or' commands

```
$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
        FROM
           $wpdb->posts,
           $wpdb->postmeta AS app_date,        
           $wpdb->postmeta AS provider,
           $wpdb->postmeta AS time1,
           $wpdb->postmeta AS time2,
           $wpdb->postmeta AS client

        WHERE
           $wpdb->posts.ID = app_date.post_id          
        AND
           $wpdb->posts.ID = provider.post_id
        AND
           $wpdb->posts.ID = time1.post_id
        AND
           $wpdb->posts.ID = time2.post_id
        AND
           $wpdb->posts.ID = client.post_id

        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'ga_appointments'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_status IN ('completed', 'publish', 'payment', 'pending')                 

        AND app_date.meta_key   = 'ga_appointment_date'
        AND app_date.meta_value = 2018-03-27

        AND provider.meta_key   = 'ga_appointment_provider'
        AND provider.meta_value = 55

        AND time1.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_time_end'
        AND time1.meta_value > 13:05

        AND time2.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_time'
        AND (time2.meta_value < 14:05

        OR  client.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_client')
        AND (client.meta_value REGEXP '\"email\";s:[1-9]+:\"jdoe@mail.com\"'

        OR  client.meta_key = 'ga_appointment_new_client')
        AND client.meta_value REGEXP '\"phone\";s:[1-9]+:\"999-656-5656\"'
    ";
```

Comment: The sql error i mentioned is gone with your code, but how can this query be shortened?

Comment: Not sure it really can.  Might want to try simplifying your REGEXP a bit.